# Load ComboBox with AD group members only once

Tags: forms, winforms, powershell, combobox, active-directory

I am working on a new user creation form in Powershell. I am using a ComboBox so that the user of the form can select the new user's line manager from a list. The list of managers is pulled from a security group in Active Directory. There are quite a few members so it takes a few seconds to load, and this delay occurs each time the ComboBox is opened. My code is below:

```
function Load-ComboBox-Managers
{
    $MgrComboBox.Items.Clear()
    $MgrArray = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "All Managers" | 
    Select-Object Name
    ForEach ($item in $MgrArray) {
        $MgrComboBox.Items.Add($item.Name)}
}
```

My question is, would it be possible to run the function only the first time the ComboBox is dropped-down, then store that list somewhere and refer to that stored list each subsequent time the ComboBox is opened, rather than querying the AD each time?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is the true issue resides with the click event of the combo box. How do you call the `function Load-ComboBox-Managers`?

Comment: I'm using the Add_Click method:

    `$MgrComboBox.Add_Click({ Load-ComboBox-Managers })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have a click event where you don't need one. If you only want to call this function once throughout your entire code, you need to remove the click event and set the items of the ComboBox once. After that they will remain constant until the instance ends or you reset them.

**Your Code:**

```
function Load-ComboBox-Managers{
    $MgrComboBox.Items.Clear()
    $MgrArray = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "All Managers" | 
    Select-Object Name
    ForEach ($item in $MgrArray) {
        $MgrComboBox.Items.Add($item.Name)}
}

$MgrComboBox.Add_Click({ Load-ComboBox-Managers })  #This line causes reinitialization
```

**Changed Code:**

```
function Load-ComboBox-Managers{
    $MgrComboBox.Items.Clear()
    $MgrArray = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "All Managers" | 
    Select-Object Name
    ForEach ($item in $MgrArray) {
        $MgrComboBox.Items.Add($item.Name)}
}
#Call the function to set the ComboBox items
Load-ComboBox-Managers
```

Additionally, if your code demands, you can set a variable to hold the list of items the ComboBox will depict, but I don't think this is the method you want to use.

```
$var = @()  #or
$Global:var = @()
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just calling the function once at the end of my script rather than using the Add_Click method. So now the combobox is populated only once upon opening the form, which is nice and clean.